# Issue with Magento 2.3.0 Installation

Tags: magento2.3.0

I have installed magento 2.3.0 with sample data successfully. backend screen is black and blank. Also not getting any thing on frontend just links are displaying and can view pages. forms, products not displaying.

Answer (score 2):

For Magento 2.3 there is issue with "\"

/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php
In above file find

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path); // approx 114 line
```

Replace with

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

It's the core issue of Magento 2.3.0 with Windows because Windows uses "\" as a separator. To fix this issue you have to change the code in the core file of Magento.

Go to path 
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php In this file find

> $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);

Replace with

> $realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));